# Update data by $id, i want to use Another Model object as controller functions parameter's and rename that parameter In Laravel

Tags: laravel, function, laravel-5.5

I send `$user->id` from blade file to `UserInformationController` (`User` and `UserInfromation` are two different models)
and my `UserInformationController` function is here:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $id)
{
     echo $id->id ;
     // it's working

}
```

But I want this kind of format:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
     echo $user->id ;
     // it's not working

}
```

Comment: what is error you got?

Comment: Its return null

Answer (score 1):

I got my ans:
It should be match with route parameter filed 
previously my function parameter didn't match with route parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$user
```

without

```
$user->id
```

because it already return the id you want to update.

Or better  just use

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 return $id;
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
      echo $user->id ;
      // its not working

}
```

Make sure the *variable* you are type-hinting in your function matches the one you left in your route.

```
Route::post('/update/{user}', ...)
```

Then you can now use **$user**